# Embedded Service Chat component in community - using "Snippet Settings File" javascript to override pre-chat file is not working

Tags: liveagent, lightning-community, chat, snap-ins

I am using chat (what was called live agent) and I am using the client side inside a Salesforce community - [As explained here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_communities.htm&type=5).

I am doing that with the `Embedded Service Chat` component in the community builder

[image]

Now, for the pre-chat fields I want to override the standard behavior by using a javascript file in a static resource - exactly as [explained here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_snippet_settings_file.htm)

This javascript file is supposed to override the pre-chat parameters defined in the `Embedded Service Deployment Settings`

**PROBLEM**

no matter what I am doing - it is not working, the override is not working and the `Embedded Service Deployment Settings` is what I see in the pre-chat window.

**REPRODUCE**

**1. Create javascript file:**

```
window._snapinsSnippetSettingsFile = (function() {
    console.log("Snippet settings file loaded.");   // Logs that the snippet settings file was loaded successfully


embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{"label":"FirstName","value":"John","displayToAgent":true},
{"label":"LastName","value":"Doe","displayToAgent":true},
{"label":"Email","value":"john.doe@salesforce.com","displayToAgent":true}];

embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatInfo = [{
"entityName": "Contact",
"showOnCreate": true,
"linkToEntityName": "Case",
"linkToEntityField": "ContactId",
"saveToTranscript": "ContactId",
"entityFieldMaps" : [{
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"FirstName",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"First Name"
}, {
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"LastName",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"Last Name"
}, {
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"Email",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"Email"
}],
}, {
"entityName":"Case",
"showOnCreate": true,
"saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
"entityFieldMaps": [{
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Subject",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Issue"
}, {
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Status",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Status"
}, {
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Origin",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Origin"
}]
}];
})();
```

**2. Save file**

with `preChat.js` file name.

**3. Upload file**

upload the file as a static resource, name it `chatEnhancedSettings`, also set the static resource as `public`.

**4. Use file in community**

In the community builder, select the chat component to edit it's parameters, and in the `Snippet Settings File` field enter: `chatEnhancedSettings`.

**5. Publish the community**

Now for my it is not working.

**QUESTIONS**

Am I doing something wrong?

Maybe I am missing some steps to make it work?

Comment: what is not working ?

Is the chat not working ? (Agent always offline) ? Prechat JS not being taken into account ?

Did you republish your Community ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I did succeed on the task to use this javascript override.

But I did it in a specific way - not as in my question

In this snippet I am disabling the creation of case and contact, and in a trigger on the `chat transcript` object I am creating them, with custom fields saved on the `chat transcript` object.

**JavaScript snippet:**

```
window._snapinsSnippetSettingsFile = (function() {

    // Logs that the snippet settings file was loaded successfully
    console.log("Snippet settings file loaded.");   

    // set all fields entered in the pre-chat widown into custom fields on the chat transcript object
    // fields without a value entered here - will get the value from the form itself
    embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatFormDetails = [
        {
            "label": "First Name",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_First_Name__c"],
            "displayToAgent":true
        },
        {
            "label": "Last Name",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_Last_Name__c"],
            "displayToAgent":true
        },
        {
            "label": "Email",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_Email__c"]
        },
        {
            "label": "Subject",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_Subject__c"],
            "displayToAgent":true
        },
        {
            "label": "Product",
            "value": "myProduct",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_Product__c"],
            "displayToAgent":true
        },
        {
            "label": "Origin",
            "value": "Chat",
            "transcriptFields": ["Form_Origin__c"]
        }
    ]; 

    // disable creation of a contact and a case:
    // this will be handled by the chat transcript trigger that will create a case that will create a contact
    embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile.extraPrechatInfo = [{
        "entityName":"Contact",
        "entityFieldMaps": [{
            "doCreate":false,
            "doFind":false,
            "fieldName":"LastName",
            "isExactMatch":false,
            "label":"Last Name"
        }, 
        {
            "doCreate":false,
            "doFind":false,
            "fieldName":"FirstName",
            "isExactMatch":false,
            "label":"First Name"
        }, 
        {
            "doCreate":false,
            "doFind":false,
            "fieldName":"Email",
            "isExactMatch":false,
            "label":"Email"
        }]
    },
    {
        "entityName":"Case",
        "entityFieldMaps": [{
            "doCreate":false,
            "doFind":false,
            "fieldName":"Subject",
            "isExactMatch":false,
            "label":"Subject"
        }]
    }];
})();
```

**Trigger - create case:**

```
trigger ChatTranscript_Trigger on LiveChatTranscript (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before insert, before update) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {       // Before Insert
        System.debug('\n\n\n\nChatTranscript_Trigger before insert\n\n\n\n');

        for (LiveChatTranscript newChat: Trigger.new) {
            // all entered fields in the pre-chat form should be copied here to the case
            Case newCase = new Case();
            newCase.SuppliedName = newChat.Form_First_Name__c;
            newCase.Web_LastName__c = newChat.Form_Last_Name__c;
            newCase.SuppliedEmail = newChat.Form_Email__c;
            newCase.Subject = newChat.Form_Subject__c;
            newCase.Product__c = newChat.Form_Product__c;
            newCase.Origin = newChat.Form_Origin__c;
            newCases.add(newCase);
        }
        insert newCases;
    }
    else if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {  // Before Update
    }
    else if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {   // Before Delete
    }  
    else if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUnDelete) {  // After UnDelete
    }
    else if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {    // After Update
    }
    else if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {    // After Delete
    }
    else if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {    // After Insert  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Upload file
>
>    upload the file as a static resource, name it **chatEnhancedSettings**, also set the static 
>      resource as public.
> 4. Use file in community
>
>    In the community builder, select the chat component to edit it's parameters, and in the 
>      Snippet Settings File field enter: **chatEnhancedSettings**

Based on what you've told us above and in reading the documentation, I believe your code should like the following:

```
window._snapinsSnippetSettingsFile = (function() {
    console.log("Snippet settings file chatEnhancedSettings loaded.");   // Logs that the snippet settings file named chatEnhancedSettings was loaded successfully


embedded_svc.chatEnhancedSettings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{"label":"FirstName","value":"John","displayToAgent":true},
{"label":"LastName","value":"Doe","displayToAgent":true},
{"label":"Email","value":"john.doe@salesforce.com","displayToAgent":true}];

embedded_svc.chatEnhancedSettings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
"entityName": "Contact",
"showOnCreate": true,
"linkToEntityName": "Case",
"linkToEntityField": "ContactId",
"saveToTranscript": "ContactId",
"entityFieldMaps" : [{
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"FirstName",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"First Name"
}, {
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"LastName",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"Last Name"
}, {
"doCreate":true,
"doFind":true,
"fieldName":"Email",
"isExactMatch":true,
"label":"Email"
}],
}, {
"entityName":"Case",
"showOnCreate": true,
"saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
"entityFieldMaps": [{
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Subject",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Issue"
}, {
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Status",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Status"
}, {
"isExactMatch": false,
"fieldName": "Origin",
"doCreate": true,
"doFind": false,
"label": "Origin"
}]
}];
```

Also, I would expect that your default "John Doe" values should be empty or `""` rather than pre-filled, but that might be a matter of preference. Example below for FirstName.

```
{"label":"FirstName","value":"","displayToAgent":true}
```

Comment: Since this is a Snippet Settings File the file MUST use "embedded_svc.snippetSettingsFile" and NOT "embedded_svc.chatEnhancedSettings". Also, the value needs to be removed for the values to save inside Transcript object fields'.